# How to decode SAMLResponse in Django View?

Tags: python, django, saml

I am writing a view to create a user in project that has logged into another site. Whenever the user logins to that site he/she gets redirected to url:`https://localhost:127.0.0.1:8000/auth/ad/reply/`.
The site sends me an SAMLResponse from which I want to extract the email address, firstname & lastname for the user.

Following is my views.py and urls.py:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

# Create your views here.
@csrf_exempt
def ad_auth(request):
    response = request.POST.get('SAMLResponse')
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/ad/reply/', ad_auth, name='ad_auth'),
]
```

Output:

```
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
```

How do I extract information from the following SAMLResponse?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is sending you a base64 encoded string.
Decode it and you will find it to be xml.

The email attribute will look something like this

```
<AttributeValue>xxxxxxxxx2810@gmail.com</AttributeValue>
```

Some sudo code to get you started

```
import base64

foo = base64.b64decode("PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnN....") # put your entire string here

print(foo)
```

Comment: ps, you might also look into python-social-auth to take care of the whole saml auth-process. 

https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/saml.html

Comment: If you are protecting anything of importance (you must be, since you are requiring authentication), then there's way more that goes into properly using SAML than just decoding and using the attributes. If you do that, then I look forward to finding your application and sending a SAML assertion that I craft, because you're not doing ANY signature validation, replay prevention, etc. I can be anyone I want to be!

Comment: I downvoted the answer, because it doesn't recommend anything for response validation, which is 100% bad security. If you don't validate and do all the other security work that you should do for SAML, then you should just leave your application public and not requiring authentication - because without that work, it's just security by obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pysaml2 and djangosaml modules to decrypt the SAMLResponse.

Comment: Thank you vishal. I will check those out.